# Put spacing between labels

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">                            
           <label>Score Content:</label><label id="lbl_lblcontent"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I put some padding between the 2 labels using bootstrap. Note that lbl_lblcontent is dynamically created.

Comment: Could you add any css code that you've tried solving this?

Comment: If you want to **only** use Bootstrap 3, I don't think there's a way, with Bootstrap 4 you have utility classes to add paddings and margins like: `p-2 mx-5`, etc

Answer (score 0):

In css you could something like this to add 10px padding to the right of only the first label...

```
.form-group label:first-child {
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty archaic but you can simply add `nbsp;`'s if you do not want to go the CSS route.

Code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">                            
           <label>Score Content:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label id="lbl_lblcontent"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```